# how to make variant display slide in bxslider?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, slider, bxslider

I want to make changeable lenght display in bxslider. First of all I did choose this.

JS

```
var sure = $('ul > li > img').data("bekleme");

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            pager: false,
            auto:true,
            controls: false,
            speed:sure
            });
    });
```

HTML

```
<ul class="bxslider">
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <img data-bekleme='<%# Eval("goruntulenmeSuresi") %>' src='/reklam/<%# Eval("yol") %>' />
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
```

but It doesn't work, can anyone help me for this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify different delays between slides in bxslider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408118/how-to-specify-different-delays-between-slides-in-bxslider)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the speed of the slider based on the total sum of each images's bekleme value?

If so, you would have to loop through the values and add them up after the document has loaded, but before you set the bxSlider plugin:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
 var $sure   = $('ul > li > img'),
        iSpeed  = 0;

    //loop through images and sum values
    $sure.each(function(index, element) {
        //make sure there's a number value
        var elementSpeed = ! isNaN($(element).attr("data-bekleme")) ? parseInt($(element).attr("data-bekleme")) : 0;
             iSpeed += elementSpeed ?  parseInt(elementSpeed) : 0;        
         });

 $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            pager: false,
            auto:true,
            controls: false,
            speed:iSpeed
  });
```

});